# Execute redis FLUSHALL command in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I want to execute Redis `FLUSHALL` every time the Rails server starts.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
port = 10000
$redis = Redis.new(:port => port)
$redis.flushall
```

http://fhwang.net/2010/09/23/Testing-Rails-against-a-running-Redis-instance-and-doing-it-with-Hydra-to-boot

To run that on start up check https://stackoverflow.com/a/7091991/643500

Comment: Also my redis port is 6379 by default, is this normal or I'm missing sth?

Comment: Did not use it before.  Port will depend on the application I believe.  Double check the documents for redis.